# How to use Git and Github for Magento source control between local and shared web server

Tags: git, magento, github, webserver

I'm developing a Magento solution and have decided to use git and github for source control.

I have a local copy of the empty repository.  We have a development (shared hosting) server with Magento now installed on, and a production cloud server.

I can't seem to figure out the most simple way to deploy the updates of my local copy to the dev and production servers.

I've always used FTP, which just seems so much easier than all the solutions I've looked at.

Any help appreciated.

On a site note, should I use three separate branches in github; one for local, dev and prod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is that add app/etc/local.xml in .gitignore file so it your db configuration of different environment will not effected on merge.

Then clone from master on each environment: local, dev and production. While working locally, you can create new branch for each new issue or enhancement. Commit and push your changes on that new branch, review (if committed by some other developer) the changes from that branch and finally merge it to master.
Now on dev and production server run the following to get your local changes:

git reset --hard HEAD
git pull origin master

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that helps a great deal, thank you.  I was thinking it would be this model as you describe.  The only problem, I guess I need to install git on the dev/prod web servers aswell?

Comment: Yes, git need to be installed on all servers in this approach. In case you dont want git things on dev/pro:
- Setup git on local
- in app/etc folder, add 2 more files {env}-local.xml. Like dev-local.xml and pro-local.xml
- update db settings in both the files based on environment.
- Write some script to move your code from local to dev/pro.
- The final step of script should move file {env}-local.xml to local.xml
- For example mv #{path}/app/etc/dev-local.xml #{path}/app/etc/local.xml'

Comment: Thank you.  Can I ask, would you recommend to have git installed on all servers and push deployments that way?  If so, I'll go ahead and have a go at setting this up.

Comment: We use git for our magento EE site and have it installed everywhere. While we only have 3 developers (2 actively using git) - we have 7 branches working at this moment. 1 Master (live site), 1 Dev (dev site), 2 VMs (each developer), and several versions of smaller changes/updates for the VM versions. This allows us to make changes locally on our VM, commit them to the dev, test how those changes interact with the modules, and then commit them to the live site.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to have git on all environments. Using some shell scripts, you can then easily automate your deployments on different environments. Coping entire code base every time won't efficient.

Comment: Thanks both for your replies.  Unfortunately I cannot find a simple guide on how to use git and github on a web server (I did manage to install it), so my efforts end here before I end up wasting too much time.  I appreciate the help

Comment: Update:  I've decided to use BitBucket instead as it has free private repositories.  I am going to simply manually pull the updates from the BitBucket repository via SSH commands on the server.

Any suggestions on how to improve this model are welcome.

Comment: Also exclude var and media folder form git repo :)